# Selenium Stops Extracting Option Text After Click Command

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium to extract dynamically loaded content. The content is on http://www.afl.com.au/stats

I am attempting to navigate to the 'Players' tab, then obtain a list of all the Seasons available. When I do this from the Teams tab, the following code works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.afl.com.au/stats')

dropdown_menu = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selTeamSeason"]'))

for option in dropdown_menu.options:
    print(option.text)
```

which gives me a list of all the options available in the Seasons tab.

However, when I click to the 'Players' tab first, I am unable to get the same list with almost identical code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.afl.com.au/stats')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stats_tab"]/ul/li[2]').click()

time.sleep(3)

dropdown_menu = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selTeamSeason"]'))

for option in dropdown_menu.options:
    print(option.text)
```

The click successfully executes, I wait for the content to update, but instead of printing all the years (2001 to 2018), Selenium prints 18 instances of empty strings. I am thoroughly stumped. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your first case , locator`(//*[@id="selTeamSeason"])` is pointing to season dropdown of Teams tab and page has only one matching node at the time ,so its working for you.
2. But in the second case , for the same locator there are 2 matching nodes are available and in this case selenium automatically pick the first one(Its an hidden element in your case).
3. So try to build a unique xpath with can work in both the tabs.
4. You can try `//div[@id='stats-player-stats']//select[@id='selTeamSeason']` locator for season dropdown in Players tab and `//div[@id='stats-team-stats']//select[@id='selTeamSeason']` for season dropdown in Teams tab

Hope this will work for you

Comment: And for selenium, get text on invisible element, selenium will return empty string. This's why when click the 'Players' tab first, all the Seasons become invisible, so option.text is empty string

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Select` just find the xpath and get all the option tags like below, tested and works.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selTeamSeason"]')
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options:
    print(option.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt the following `Locator Strategy` worked on the default **`TEAMS`** TAB :

```
dropdown_menu = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selTeamSeason"]'))
```

As the first match as per the `Locator Strategy` was the `Dropdown` itself which is not the case when dealing with **`PLAYERS`** TAB. On **`PLAYERS`** TAB to list of all the options available in the **`Seasons`** `Dropdown` you can use the following code block :

```
dropdown_menu = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='stats-player-stats']//select[@id='selTeamSeason']"))
for option in dropdown_menu.options:
    print(option.text)
```